# DevExpress - Unable to Load Document Preview Control in WPF 16.2

Tags: wpf, devexpress, wpftoolkit, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

I've added a DocumentPreviewControl as per the sample instructions for static report; however when I run our application It's crashed bug when I run the application from a client machine (not developer).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq9rW.png)

All dll Files are Attched in deployed exe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSOHt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved by using This Method DevExpress-->All Platforme-->DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool

*Chose Path

*Click Analyze

*Goto Path

*Copy all files and Replace them on Client Machine [installed directory]

(^_^)